# "undefined reference to 'pantheios_log_3_no_test'"

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, ld, pantheios

I'm having trouble linking with Pantheios on Linux with gcc4.6 with the following error:

```
In function `pantheios::internal::log_dispatch_3(int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int, char const*)':
sig_writing_sink.cpp:(.text._ZN9pantheios8internal14log_dispatch_3EijPKcjS2_jS2_[pantheios::internal::log_dispatch_3(int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int, char const*)]+0x6d): undefined reference to `pantheios_log_3_no_test'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm linking with:

- `libpantheios.1.core.gcc46.mt.a`
- `libpantheios.1.fe.simple.gcc46.mt.a`
- `libpantheios.1.be.fprintf.gcc46.mt.a`
- `libpantheios.1.bec.fprintf.gcc46.mt.a`
- `libpantheios.1.util.gcc46.mt.a`
- `libpantheios.1.appl.gcc46.mt.a`
- `libpantheios.1.core.gcc46.mt.a`

Where is `pantheios_log_3_no_test`?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that in gcc, symbols are only linked forward, so dependent symbols in a given lib will only be resolved from the libs that follow it in the link list. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc) for some more details.
By moving other statically linked libs to *before* Pantheios, the linker succeeded.